# Nomenclatura Correta de Grupos de Usuários de um Sistema

Tags: terminologia, modelagem, design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software

Estou fazendo o projeto de um sistema que terá vários módulos. É possível até que esses módulos sejam separados em aplicativos diferentes. Aí me veio uma dúvida que já tive anteriormente mas não consegui obter a resposta:

Que nomes devo dar aos diferentes tipos de usuários dos módulos de um sistema? Existe um padrão?

Exemplo existente: **Uber**

O Uber, com seus usuários motoristas e usuários passageiros, possui um aplicativo para cada um desses tipos de usuários. O Uber declara que os motoristas são seus parceiros e não empregados (e nem clientes). Mas e os passageiros? São clientes do Uber ou dos usuários motoristas? Entendem onde quero chegar?

Meu caso:

No **caso do meu projeto**, o meu cliente seria uma série de profissionais diferentes que seriam a fonte de renda do sistema, e eles seriam usuários de um módulo próprio para eles. Esses meus clientes tem seus próprios clientes, que usariam outro módulo separado para usar os serviços dos profissionais já mencionados. Estes usuários (clientes do meus clientes) não pagariam para usar o sistema. Além disso, existem os usuários que administram os clientes (profissionais) do sistema, usando um módulo CRM que será feito para isso.

No final, existem pelo menos 4 tipos de usuários:

- Meus clientes
- Clientes dos meus clientes
- Funcionários dos meus clientes, com perfil de acesso mais restrito
- Gestores dos meus clientes (meus colaboradores)

**Então, como deveria nomear cada módulo e seus usuários? sabendo que ainda existe o módulo aberto, que pode ser acessado sem necessidade de autenticação...**

Answer (score -1):

Resumo: Perfil.

Você pode ter em uma mesma tabela os dois tipos de usuário, com registros quase iguais, sendo diferenciados apenas por um perfil.

Ja na sua aplicação (ou aplicações) você pode ter um único tipo de login, que pede apenas usuário e senha ou login por facebook/google, e na hora de identificar o usuário, você busca também o perfil associado e direciona para páginas ou layouts diferentes.

Essa tratativa seria bem parecida à perfis diferentes dentro de uma aplicação, por exemplo um usuário estagiário pode ver apenas o menu de consulta, já um usuário analista pode ver os menus de consulta e solicitação, e um usuário gerente pode ver consulta, solicitação, aprovação e relatórios. O controle de quais menus, funcionalidades ou páginas, são ou não exibidos depende do tipo do perfil logado e não do usuário em si.

EDIT:
Acabei esquecendo que dizer que a forma como você está fazendo não é muito usada, pelo menos não é a forma que eu vi sendo feita pelas empresas e projetos que passei, a menos que seja uma aplicação totalmente diferente, outro contexto, outra segmento, os usuários são tratados como "iguais" e diferenciados pelos perfis.

Comment: Todos esses conceitos eu já uso. A pergunta não é sobre isso. É sobre **nomenclatura** apenas, e não sobre a tecnologia ou arquitetura de software usados. Mesmo assim obrigada.